# Active cron job

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task

I am trying to make a cron job for the first time but i have some problems making it work.

Here is what i have done so far:

**Linux commands**:

```
crontab -e
```

My cronjob looks like this:

```
1 * * * * wget -qO /dev/null http://mySite/myController/myView
```

Now when i look in:

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/
```

I get the following output:

```
marc root
```

if i open the file `root`

i see my cronjob (the one above)

However it doesnt seem like it is running.

is there a way i can check if its running or make sure that it is running?

Comment: make a log out of it and check >> would do

Comment: Can you check the server logs to see the wget requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default cron jobs do have a log file. It should be in `/var/log/syslog` (depends on your system). Vouch for it and you're done. Else you can simply append the output to a log file manually by

```
1 * * * * wget http://mySite/myController/myView >> ~/my_log_file.txt
```

and see what's your output. Notice I've changed removed the `quiet` parameter from wget command so that there is some output.